# Reverse Proxy in CakePHP?

Tags: apache, cakephp, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I've got a CakePHP application, and the following directives in my httpd.conf

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /forum/ http://somesite.com/phpbb3
ProxyPass /gallery/ http://someothersite.com/gallery3
<Location /forum/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
<Location /gallery/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

Without CakePHP this works fine - but because CakePHP is using it's own redirection logic from routes.php and other sources, it seems to override any proxy settings, so any call to "/community" on my server follows the default pathway of looking for a Controller called CommunityController.

My issue here is that I want to have one server that serves muliple applications, but keep it seamless to the user - so a complete PHPBB application can for instance run within the "/forum" directory as if it were a controller in CakePHP.

Has anyone done this before, and can it be done?  Why does `mod_rewrite` and/or the routes.php file override my `mod_proxy` directives??

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of using mod_proxy, you could use mod_rewrite to create a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive with the `[P]` (proxy) flag in conjunction with the `[L]` (last rule) flag.

**'proxy|P' (force proxy):**

> This flag
>   forces the substitution part to be
>   internally sent as a proxy request and
>   immediately (rewrite processing stops
>   here) put through the proxy module.
>   You must make sure that the
>   substitution string is a valid URI
>   (typically starting with
>   http://hostname) which can be handled
>   by the Apache proxy module. If not,
>   you will get an error from the proxy
>   module. Use this flag to achieve a
>   more powerful implementation of the
>   ProxyPass directive, to map remote
>   content into the namespace of the
>   local server.
>
> Note: mod_proxy must be enabled in
>   order to use this flag.

**'last|L' (last rule):**

> Stop the
>   rewriting process here and don't apply
>   any more rewrite rules. This
>   corresponds to the Perl last command
>   or the break command in C. Use this
>   flag to prevent the currently
>   rewritten URL from being rewritten
>   further by following rules. For
>   example, use it to rewrite the
>   root-path URL ('/') to a real one,
>   e.g., '/e/www/'.

Comment: I'd looked at that but I read that there would be a performance hit if I used mod rewrite. 

I guess my main question is WHY doesn't mod_proxy take precedence over CakePHPs routing?